# In fxpmath does the signed syntax represent the negative numbers as 1's complement only? If yes, how do I change it to 2's complement?

Tags: python, data-conversion, twos-complement, ones-complement

```
from fxpmath import Fxp

c = Fxp(complex(3.2500+2.0625j), True, 8, 4) # (val, signed, n_word, n_frac)

print(c)

print((c).bin()) # binary representation

d = Fxp(complex(2.0625+5.2500j), True, 8, 4) # (val, signed, n_word, n_frac)

print(d)

print((d).bin()) # binary representation

y= Fxp(complex(c*d), True, 16,8)

print(y)

print((y).bin()) # binary representation**
```

This is the output I see-

```
(3.25+2.0625j)

00110100+00100001j

(2.0625+5.25j)

00100001+01010100j


(-4.125+21.31640625j)

1111101111100000+0001010101010001j
```

when I multiply these two numbers, the real part is -4.125 and the conversion to binary shows just the 1's complement of the answer, I need this to be shown in 2's complement, is this possible using the fxpmath function?
The real part and the imaginary part again consists of integer and fraction bits each 8bit wide.

Comment: Please show the code for this multiplication & conversion to binary.

Comment: @ScottHunter I have added the code in the main thread for reference. thank you for looking into it.

Comment: The 'signed' in the fxpmath syntax is converting the negative number into 1's complement whereas I am looking to get the answer in 2's complement.

Comment: Update your original question to include your code rather than posting it in an answer to your original question.

Comment: @mohammedzeeshan: That's not how Stack Overflow is structured. It's not a thread, with a chain of replies; you've posted in the answer section. You should edit that information into the question instead.

Comment: Looking at the examples on the github page, it looks like the `bin` method already gives two's complement. Are you *sure* you're getting one's complement?

Comment: @user2357112 thanks for the update, will take care.

Comment: @user2357112 yes I am sure, ill go ahead and paste the output as well in the main question.

Comment: That's two's complement.

Comment: @user2357112 my mistake, I was performing the complements for the integer bit separately, understood it now. thanks for your time.